# Alternating Capital Letters in Array Using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an alphanumeric string like below,

```
$string_1 = "a4nas60dj71wiena15sdl1131kg12b"
```

and would like to change it to something like below,

```
$string_2 = "a4NaS60dJ71wIeNa15Sdl1131Kg12B"
```

How would I go about doing this?  I have tried the below code, but it doesn't work.

```
$lenght = strlen($string_1);

for ( $i = 0; $i <= $length - 1; $i += 1) {

    if ( $i % 2) {

        $string_2[$i]=strtoupper($string_1[$i]);

    }

    else {

        $string_2[$i]=$string_1[$i];

    }

}

echo $string_2;
```

The above code prints out "Array" so something is definitely not working.

Comment: you misspelled the first $length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, you have a slight error in your capitalized string:

```
$string_1: a4nas60dj71wiena15sdl1131kg12b
$string_2: a4NaS60dJ71wIeNa15Sdl1131Kg12B
                               ^ should be capital so out of sync for rest of string
```

I'll give you two ways of doing it:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$string_1 = "a4nas60dj71wiena15sdl1131kg12b";
$string_2 = "a4NaS60dJ71wIeNa15Sdl1131Kg12B";

$letter_count = 0;
$result = '';
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string_1); $i++) {
    if (!preg_match('![a-zA-Z]!', $string_1[$i])) {
        $result .= $string_1[$i];
    } else if ($letter_count++ & 1) {
        $result .= strtoupper($string_1[$i]);
    } else {
        $result .= $string_1[$i];
    }
}

$result2 = preg_replace_callback('!([a-zA-Z]\d*)([a-zA-Z])!', 'convert_to_upper', $string_1);

function convert_to_upper($matches) {
    return strtolower($matches[1]) . strtoupper($matches[2]);
}

echo "$string_1\n";
echo "$string_2\n";
echo "$result\n";
echo "$result2\n";
?>
```

**Note:** The above makes several assumptions:

1. Characters other than numbers and letters can be in the string;
2. You want to alternate case regardless of the original (eg "ASDF" becomes "aSdF");
3. You're capitalizing every second letter, not every second lowercase letter.

The above can be altered if these assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for going above and beyond the question and giving me two ways of doing it.  First, the assumptions you made were fine for this scenario.  Second, is there one of these examples that is better than the other?

Answer (score 0):

Strings are not arrays, and you're declaring $string_2 as an array...

Still, your code won't work quite as expected, since, you're alternating case of every other *letter*, while ignoring numbers

try the following:

```
function altCaps($str) {
    $lower = true;
    $str2 = "";
    for ($i=0;$len=strlen($str);$i<$len;++$i) {
        $char = substr($str,$i,1);
        if (is_numeric($char)) {
            $str2 .= $char;
        } else {
            if ($lower) {
                $str2 .= strtolower($char);
            } else {
                $str2 .= strtolower($char);
            }
            $lower = !$lower;
        }
    }
    return $str2;
}
```

Comment: This will count hyphens, periods, and other non-numeric characters as letters.

Comment: while true, his string format doesn't include any of those characters

Comment: @Skidmore, The original question says "alphanumeric string" so those characters don't need to be handled at all.

Comment: @strager, you're correct. I apologize, I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You should be good to go with this function. Just call **alternate('string here');** and it will work perfectly.

This works with hyphens, white space, periods, etc. included in the string.

```
function alternate($string1)
{
    $do_caps = false;
    $string2 = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string1); $i++)
    {
      $char = substr($string1, $i, 1);
      if (stripos('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', $char) !== false)
      {
            if ($do_caps)
            {
                $char = strtoupper($char);
                $do_caps = false;
            }
            else
            {
                $do_caps = true;
            }
      }
      $string2 .= $char;
    }
    return $string2;
}
```